# Let $a_1, \ldots,\ a_{100}$ be $100$ positive integers. Show that for some $m,\ n$ with $1\le m\le n\le 100, \sum_{i=m}^n a_i$ is divisible by $100$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a_1,\ a_2,\ a_3, \ldots,\ a_{100}$ be $100$ positive integers. Show that for some $m,\ n$ with $1\le m\le n\le 100, \sum_{i=m}^n a_i$ is divisible by $100$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the partial sums $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$, where $1\leq n\leq100$. If $s_i$ is divisible by $100$ for some $i$ then we are done. Otherwise, since there are $100$ of the $s_i$ and $99$ possible remainders upon division by $100$, two of the $s_i$, say $s_n$ and $s_m$ with $m>n$, must be equal modulo $100$. Then $s_n-s_m = \sum_{i=m}^n a_i$ is divisible by $100$, as desired.

Comment: this is a great idea!

Comment: why will two of $s_i$ be equal to mod $100$?

Comment: @sourish Two of the $s_i$ will be equal mod $100$ because of the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). Think of the possible values mod $100$ as boxes and place each number $s_i$, $1\leq i\leq100$, (the pigeons) in the box representing its value mod $100$. We're putting $100$ pigeons in $99$ holes, so there is at least one hole with two pigeons.

Comment: @user134824 Sir, that was great reasoning. Kindly edit m>n to m<n.

Comment: @user134824 Sir I re-framed the problem as : having hundred natural numbers, there  are some natural numbers such that whose sum is divisible by 100. Is this true or not. I'm asking that if I rearrange $a_1,\dots ,a_{100}$ as $a_{48},a_{49},\dots ,a_{100},a_1,a_2\dots ,a_{47}$  for our convenience then doing this is there any loss of generality or not. If yes then how? Kindly help.